# How to use a lambda operation input in a function parameter?

Tags: f#

To be honest, I am not even sure how to correctly phrase the question.

I want to write a function which can accept a lambda operation i.e. (x -> x + x) as a parameter which is then applied to each entry of a list. This task is from the F# - Accumulate task by [exercism.io](https://exercism.io/my/solutions/c2c23aef5af241efadd69eaa929ed15f).

As I did not find any example of this kind of function input, I have no idea how I can use this lambda input.

Comment: I believe you misunderstood something. A lambda expression can be made with the `fun` keyword. A lambda expression is just another function, so your function should simply take a function as one argument. When you call the function, you can choose to write a lambda expression instead of a function name, or whatever else. You don't define a function as explicitly taking a lambda expression as parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Higher-order functions

A function that accepts a lambda as a parameter is called a "higher-order function". These are very common in functional programming. Here's a simple example called `apply`, which is a higher-order function that takes another function (or lambda) called `f` and applies it to a value `x`.

```ml
// ('a -> 'b) -> 'a -> 'b
let apply f x = f x
```

### List.map

Any higher-order function that applies a given function to every element of a collection is called a "map". For lists, the specific function you want is called `List.map`, and is already [provided by the F# standard library](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-collections-listmodule.html#map).

### Implementing your own map function

If you're not allowed to use the built-in `List.map` for this exercise, you can implement the same thing yourself easily via recursion. I don't want to give away the solution prematurely, so I'll describe it in pseudo-code first:

- Given a function `f` and a list of `items`:

  - If `items` is empty, return the empty list
  - Else `items` is not empty:

    - Let `value` be the result of applying `f` to the first element of `items`
    - Let `rest` be the result of recursively mapping `f` to the remainder of the `items`
    - Return a new list that consists of `value` followed by `rest`.

Hint: Use [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/pattern-matching) to convert this into F# code.

### Solution

> ```
>  let rec mymap f items =
>      match items with
>          | [] -> []
>          | head :: tail ->
>             let value = f head
>             let rest = mymap f tail
>             value :: rest
> ```

Note: This is a verbose implementation. If desired, you can make it considerably smaller.